# promise executing function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, undefined-function

I am trying to return a value inside of a promise when the promise resolves, then pass the returned value to my state. However, the return value of my function no matter what I try... is undefined.

My function is imported from an npm package which has its documentation here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/synonyms

it is meant to return a synonym of a given word.

Maybe there is some really obvious issue with the way I structured the promise itself that is causing some bad async timing?

I have tried returning only the function without passing it to resolve but this throws an error

```
searchForSynonymsAndDef = (param) =>{
if(this.state.scholarMode==true){
console.log("INSIDE SYNONYMS")

var synonyms = require("synonyms");

  let p = new Promise((resolve,reject,param)=>{
    var result=resolve(synonyms(param,"n"))

  }).then((result)=>{
    console.log("result is:",result)
  })
  .then((result)=>{
    this.setState({textToReadAloud: "here are some synonyms for "
    +param +"...firstly.....nouns...."+result})
    console.log("here are some synonyms for "+param +"...firstly.....nouns...."+result)
    })
  }else{
    console.log("sorry scholar mode is off")
  }
}
```

I expect 'result' to be a synonym based on the passed in param but unfortunately result is always = undefined :(

Comment: Get rid of the first `then()`. You don't return anything to it so the next `then()` is seeing `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass param to promise. Just remove param from Promise and it should work.

```
searchForSynonymsAndDef = (param) =>{
if(this.state.scholarMode==true){
console.log("INSIDE SYNONYMS")

var synonyms = require("synonyms");

  let p = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    var result=resolve(synonyms(param,"n"))

  }).then((result)=>{
    console.log("result is:",result)
  })
  .then((result)=>{
    this.setState({textToReadAloud: "here are some synonyms for "
    +param +"...firstly.....nouns...."+result})
    console.log("here are some synonyms for "+param +"...firstly.....nouns...."+result)
    })
  }else{
    console.log("sorry scholar mode is off")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help now the code runs but my result is simply 'undefined'

Comment: could this perhaps be an issue with the way I am including my 'synonyms'

Answer (score 0):

```
searchForSynonymsAndDef = (param) =>{
    if(this.state.scholarMode==true){
    console.log("INSIDE SYNONYMS")

    var synonyms = require("synonyms");
    let p = new Promise((resolve,reject,param)=>{
        resolve(synonyms(param,"n"));
    });
    return p;
}else{
    console.log("sorry scholar mode is off")
}
}
```